# Existence of a linear map in general position

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Let $W$ and $T$ be linear spaces over $\mathbb F$, with $n=\dim(W)$ and $t=\dim(T)$. Let $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ be a family of subspaces of $W$ with $\dim(U_i)=r_i$ for each $i$.

The linear map $\phi:W\to T$ is defined to be *in general position* (with respect to the $U_i$) iff $\dim(\phi(U_i))=\min\{r_i,t\}$ for each $i$. In other words, $\dim(\phi(U_i))$ is the maximum possible for each $i$.

The theorem states that given a large enough field, such a linear map always exists. Formally, if the field $\mathbb F$ has order $> (n-t)(m+1)$, then a linear map $\phi:W\to T$ in general position always exists.

Does anyone know of a reference to the proof of this theorem? I found it in  the textbook "Linear Algebra Methods in Combinatorics" by Babai and Frankl, Theorem 3.13, page 63. (The textbook is easily found online.) However, the proof seems to be wrong, specifically Proposition 3.9, whose statement seems to be false... or maybe I'm confused?

Edit: Resolved, thanks! See the comments.

Comment: It seems that the statement of Proposition 3.9 is a bit sloppy, but I think what the author means is that there exists a polynomial $f$ whose variables are (part of) the entries of the $k - r$ rows of the matrix $A$ and if the polynomial doesn't vanish, then the matrix $A$ has full rank. Thus, $A$ will be of full rank on a "large set" (the complement of the set of zeros of $f$). If the polynomial vanishes, the matrix $A$ can still have full rank so this is not an if and only if statement unlike the statement of the proposition might suggest. Is this not enough for the proof to go through?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the entire proof does go through.